# How do I run a specific release of Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I've updated to 0.6.0 but would like to run my project in 0.5.8. So when I run:

> meteor --release 0.5.8

it returns

> 0.5.8: unknown release.

What is the correct format for targeting a specific release?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You would need to use a meteorite to use older versions : https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite. For the moment `--release` can't target older versions of meteor to 0.6.0.

Install meteorite via

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

Then in your project run `mrt` so that it allows meteorite to localize the project to one version of meteor.

You will notice meteorite has created a smart.json in your project. Edit the `smart.json` it creates to something like

```
{
    "meteor": {
    "tag": "v0.5.8"
}
```

Then just run `mrt` to get it running meteor version `0.5.8`. Only that project would be affected. So your other projects can still run 0.6.0

Of note is meteorite is also very helpful. It allows you to use the packages over at http://atmosphere.meteor.com/ in your project.

Update: To use versions above 0.6.0 on your meteor use --release. e.g

```
meteor --release 0.6.1
```

Answer (score 7):

For Meteor releases above 0.6.0, you can add the `--release` tag to any `meteor` command:

```
meteor create test --release 0.6.0
```

Meteorite can easily pull down earlier releases:

```
mrt create test --tag v0.5.9
```

The result is a "smart.json" file that will install the previous Meteor version when you run `mrt`. You could also manually edit the "smart.json" file:

```
{
  "meteor": {
    "git": "https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git",
    "tag": "v0.5.9"
  },
  "packages": {}
}
```

Comment: You should fix the Meteor version you specified: 6.0.0 => 0.6.0 (since meteor hasn't passed 1.x yet). I tried to edit it but it wasn't enough characters for stack overflow's liking.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't target any release prior to 0.6.0, this feature is only going to help when the next releases of Meteor come out.